# JavaFX block non UI Thread until GUI has finished updating (In Pause Transition)

Tags: java, javafx

I want to visualize my HeapSort. Basically when I swap two elements in an array I also want to change the bars of my graph representing the values of the array. See image below.

I use a PauseTransition after each array swap, as I want to visualize each single swap also in the GUI, however, the complete algorithm finishes before the delay of the first pause transition is over and so not every single step is shown on the GUI but only the end result.

**I need to block the non UI Thread, so that each swap is shown.**

**I have tried**
`Thread.sleep(1000)`

> But the GUI is hidden until the array is sorted

**Here my swapElements code snippet**

```
private void swapElements(int parentIndex, int childIndex) {
    int tempParent = array[parentIndex];
    array[parentIndex] = array[childIndex];
    array[childIndex] = tempParent;


    PauseTransition wait = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));

    wait.setOnFinished((e) -> {
        Bar parentBar = Controller.bars.get(parentIndex);
        Controller.bars.set(parentIndex, Controller.bars.get(childIndex));
        Controller.bars.set(childIndex, parentBar);
    });
    wait.play();
}
```

**Here my Controller:**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
public HBox hBox;
public static ObservableList<Bar> bars = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    bars.addListener(new ListChangeListener<Bar>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends Bar> c) {
            runOnUiThread();
        }
    });

    HeapSort heapSort = new HeapSort();
    heapSort.heapIT();
}

public void runOnUiThread(){
    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hBox.getChildren().setAll(bars);
        }
    });
}
}
```

PS. I fill the `bars` list when I execute `heapIT` in my `HeapSort` I left it away and the algorithm as it's not relevant for my problem (IMO)

**Sample Image of the graph:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might be best off doing full MVC.  You have it mostly done.

Have the controller tell the model about the update in the sort.  Then have the controller wait till the GUI updates.  How?  Have the GUI notify the model when the transition is done which the controller will listen for.  When the controller hears the that the GUI is updated, it can process the next step.

You'll need a hook to know when the sorting is completed.

FWIW: Not totally familiar with jaavafx transitions so I'm not sure how to listen for the transition to complete but I'd imagine there is a way (over-ride a method or listen for an event)